# D3 - where do I need to put my "draw" or "redraw" function to enable redraw on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a bar graph. It shows flu vaccination rate by state.  By clicking on the legend, you can switch between demographies in each state, great!

However, it takes a *double* click on the legend to redraw.  One click successfully kills the bars, but it takes a second click to redraw them.

Working example is here.  I think I'm calling my functions in the wrong order?

http://bl.ocks.org/greencracker/862062268ab398df4757

roughly, its:

```
declarations
d3.json (read in json){
    coerce data into numbers
    draw(input)  
    }

function draw (input) {
  draw bars here
  draw legend here
      legend.on("click", function (d) {return do_two_things(d);)
  }

function kill() {
   svg.selectAll(".bar")
   .remove()
}

function do_two_things(input) {
    kill();
    draw(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the transition. It means that the bars/axes aren't removed immediately. However, the code to re-draw everything *is* run immediately. When that code runs, the bars are still there, selected, the data matched to them, and hence the `.enter()` selection is empty.

The easiest way to fix this is to remove the transition, see [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/65d5e0f4de6bc6ab413b). If you want to keep it, you need to stagger the two code blocks, making sure that the second one executes only when everything has been removed. You can use for example the [`transition.each("end", ...)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-each) event handler for this, but it will make your code a bit more involved. You can also simply use `setTimeout()`, see [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/ea47bcef1edfc7f00c84).